# Using anyOf and not to pick combinations of elements in an object and eliminate others

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a composite object made up of 3 elements. I want to be able to allow certain combinations of the elements and to allow showing one of the 3 elements. This is dependent on some state. Here is the object created for simplicity showing the 3 elements:

```
      {
       "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
       "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/long-schema",
       "type": "object",
       "properties": {
          "propA": { "$ref": "#/$defs/objectA" },
          "propB": { "$ref": "#/$defs/objectB" },
          "propC": { "$ref": "#/$defs/objectC" }
      },
       "$defs": {
          "objectA": {
            "type": "object",
            "a": { "type": "string", "enum": ["A"] }
          },
          "objectB": {
            "type": "object",
            "b": { "type": "string", "enum": ["B"] }
          },
          "objectC": {
            "type": "object",
            "c": { "type": "string", "enum": ["C"] }
          }
        }
      }
```

I believe a combination of anyOf and not should be able to accomplish this but I am not very sure how to use them in the correct combination or the syntax required: The 'not' here is isolated so I'm sure that's not how to combine it

Here is some beginnings of what I am trying to achieve:

```
 //Display any combination of B and C but not A
   "anyOf" : [
      "not":{ "$ref": "#/$defs/objectA" },
      "$comment" : "Choose objects B, C or B & C, but not A"
   ]

 //Display any combination of A and B but not C
    "anyOf" : [
          "not":{ "$ref": "#/$defs/objectC" },
          "$comment" : "A and B but not C, allowing any combination of A and B"
       ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Since you have a number of conditions, all of which must be met, you can put those inside `allOf`. You also need to make the items inside `anyOf` and `allOf` into objects (schemas).

Since you already define what the properties must contain in the above section, you only need to add what properties can and cannot appear. "Property X should not be present" can be represented with a `not` and `required`.

```
// type, properties, $defs here...
"allOf": [
  {
    //Display any combination of B and C but not A
    "$comment" : "Choose objects B, C or B & C, but not A",
    "not": { "required": [ "propA" ] },
    "anyOf": [
      { "required": ["propB"] },
      { "required": ["propC"] }
    ]
  },
  {
    //Display any combination of A and B but not C
    "$comment" : "A and B but not C, allowing any combination of A and B"
    "anyOf": [
      { "required": ["propA"] },
      { "required": ["propB"] }
    ],
    "not": { "required": [ "propC" ] }
  }
]
```

You can read more about declaring conditional conditions here: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, I did not think you could combine them like that.